# How to remove spacing from figure created with imshow()?

Tags: matplotlib

I have a matrix that I want to show (`np.asarray(vectors).T`) and so far everything works *except* that the image is having way to much padding below the bottom x-axis.

I tried to use `tight_layout()` but it has absolutely no effect.

How can I crop my image correctly such that there is not so much spacing

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Creating fake data

topn = 15
nb_classes = 13
rows = 27
columns = nb_classes * topn    
labels = ['Class {:d}'.format(i) for i in range(nb_classes)]    
m = np.random.random((rows,columns))

# Plotting

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(m, interpolation='none')
plt.grid(False)    
plt.xlabel('Word', size=16)
plt.ylabel('Dimension', size=16)

ax = plt.gca() 
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position("right")
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position("top")

yticks = list()
for i in range(0, nb_classes):
    if i != 0:
        plt.axvline(i*n - 0.5, c='w')
    yticks.append((i*n - 0.5 + n/2))

plt.xticks(yticks, labels, rotation=90)    
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This is the resulting image (grey lines just to visualize the size):

---

[image]

---

Comment: Try to add `aspect='auto'` to the call of `plt.imshow`. Is this what you want? (see [here](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html))

Comment: @Michael Hm, the spacing is gone but now each pixel is "stretched" along the y-axis.

Comment: If you want neither a large blank space nor streched pixels, you should probably try `plt.figure(figsize=(x,y))` and make a smaller figure.

Comment: @Michael Ah, using both in combination did the trick. I tried both separately but I have to set `aspect='auto'` *and* `figsize=(8,4)` in order to get what I desire. Thank you! Are you going to provide the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))` and `aspect='auto'` in the call of `plt.imshow`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Creating fake data

topn = 15
nb_classes = 13
rows = 27
columns = nb_classes * topn    
labels = ['Class {:d}'.format(i) for i in range(nb_classes)]    
m = np.random.random((rows,columns))

# Plotting

plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
plt.imshow(m, interpolation='None', aspect='auto')
plt.grid(False)    
plt.xlabel('Word', size=16)
plt.ylabel('Dimension', size=16)

ax = plt.gca() 
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position("right")
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position("top")

yticks = list()
for i in range(0, nb_classes):
    if i != 0:
        plt.axvline(i*n - 0.5, c='w')
    yticks.append((i*n - 0.5 + n/2))

plt.xticks(yticks, labels, rotation=90)    
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```